# Eclipse: how to open a search-found file in a new editor tab?

Tags: eclipse

I constantly use Eclipse's find-in-file feature this way:

Search->File->File Search tab.

When I get a list of files containing my search string, these files shows in the bottom pane. When I click, in the bottom pane, the line in a file that contains the search string, the file is always opened in the same file editor tab, and so the file I opened earlier that contains the search string is gone. I am hoping to open several files at the same time that contain the search string.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the **Search** preference page, uncheck the box for **Reuse editors to show matches**.

Comment: Under Search->Preferences, there are four options: Workspace, Project, Hierarchy, and Working Set. I saw the same message for each option: The operation is unavailable on the current selection. Please select a valid Java element name. A similar message goes for Javascript too. Did I miss something? Am I looking at the right place? Thanks for help.

Comment: I got it. It is under Windows->Preferences